# Temporizador mientras el programa corre en C++ ¿Utilizar Hilos?

Tags: c++, hilos, dev-c++

Recurro a StackOverflow, porque no encuentro material explicativo sobre la programacion de **Hilos en C++**.

El caso es que estoy haciendo un juego y necesito mostrar al jugador un **temporizador** en una parte de la pantalla a medida que el usuario va jugando, para que sepa cuanto tiempo le queda para completar el objetivo y que al acabar dicho tiempo, el juego se detenga y le avise al jugador de que su tiempo se terminó.
 Investigando llegué al tema de los *Hilos*, en el que puedo ejecutar **dos procesos o más a la misma vez** (El Juego y El Temporizador).

Quizás haya otra mejor manera de realizar este procedimiento por favor decirme, de lo contrario necesito las funciones para utilizar hilos.

Utilizo *Dev-C++* y programo el juego con la libreria *Winbgim.h*

Comment: No se pueden hacer hilos en c++

Comment: Si se pueden hacer hilos en c++ con la clase thread y con la biblioteca pthread de c, solo no son necesarios para esta tarea

Comment: Sino me equivoco, el compilador que usa Dev-C++ no soporta la librería `<thread>` (añadida en el estandar C++11). Personalmente, te recomendaría que cambies a otro IDE como CodeBlocks, CLion o Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: @Xam No es que Dev-C++ no soporte esa librería... una cosa es el IDE y otra el compilador. Dev es un producto descontinuado y obsoleto que contiene, a su vez, un compilador MinGW obsoleto... nada te impide jugar a actualizar el compilador y comprobar los resultados... no es lo recomendable pero sí es posible. Tenemos que aprender a separar IDE de compilador... son dos cosas totalmente diferentes

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que para obtener lo que vos buscas no es necesario utilizar hilos, simplemente necesitas hacer llamados a la funcion `time(NULL)` que te da como resultado cuantos segundos pasaron desde el epoch.
 Por lo general en un videojeugo tendras una funcion que actualiza el estado y luego una que dibuja los elementos en pantalla:

```
#include <time.h>

class temporizador{

public:

    temporizador(){}
    ~temporizador(){}

    void init(time_t temp_duration){

      initial_time = time(NULL);
      temp = temp_duration;

    }

    void update(){

      static time_t lastTime = initial_time;
      time_t deltaTime;
//Sacamos la diferencia de tiempo desde la ultima iteracion y la actual
      deltaTime = time(NULL) - lastTime;
//Actualizamos el tiempo restante
      temp -= deltaTime;
//Almacenamos el tiempo de la iteracion actual
      lastTime += deltaTime;
    }

private:
    time_t temp;
    time_t initial_time;
};
```

---

Edicion:
Me pidieron un ejemplo de la funcion time con outputs, este programa lo demuestra de manera sencilla con un tiempo de inicio, fin y diferencial:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    time_t inicio;
    time_t fin;
    time_t delta;

    inicio = time(NULL);

    printf("El tiempo de inicio es %d segundos\n",inicio );

    //esperamos 1 segundo
    sleep(1);

    fin = time(NULL);

    delta = fin - inicio;

    printf("El tiempo de fin es %d\nTranscurrieron %d segundos\n", fin, delta );

    return 0;
}
```

En mi caso el output que produjo fue:

```
El tiempo de inicio es 1529347100 segundos
El tiempo de fin es 1529347101 segundos
Transcurrieron 1 segundos
```

Comment: No soy muy experto con c++ y `time`, Podria darme un ejemplo más completo, utilizando éstos cálculos e irlos mostrando en pantalla en **segundos**

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien...la salida está en formato epoch y yo la quisiera en formato de (m/d/y h:m:s), y extraer los segundos, para que en el output me aparezca `El tiempo de inicio es: 30 segundos, el tiempo de fin: 55 segundos` por ejemplo. Ya que lo que pretendo es ir actualizando los segundos en la pantalla a medida que van transcurriendo el tiempo.

Comment: @LordOfDreams el problema aquí es que no estás currándotelo nada... pides que te lo den todo hecho y tu no estás aportando absolutamente nada. [es.so] es gratuíto sí... pero por simple respeto deberías tener la consideración de pensar que lo mismo es necesario que tú también aportes tu granito de arena... si quieres que te den el trabajo hecho tal vez debas plantearte pagar a alguien por hacer tu trabajo. Si resulta que, como dices no eres experto en C++ y time no pasa nada... hay miles de tutoriales en internet (eso y que el código de Sacha es C, no tiene nada exclusivo de C++)